# How to enable view/edit/delete tab options in the post?

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, drupal-8

I am trying to learn Drupal from today & during this by mistake i remove the checkbox from the options & now those options are not there to check it again & even i am not able to find them anywhere.

here is the imgur link of the problem
top one is after the menu disabled
below one is with the menu which i need to bring again.

[Before i change settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMBNi.png)

[After i change settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UvDk.png)

both images are different because first one is from the tutorial which i was watching & second one is mine.

Link of the forum where i asked question
www.drupal.org/node/2664514

Answer (score 1):

You can get your tabs back.
Go to block layout -> then configure Tabs in content block -> check the show primary tabs in shown tabs and save it.

Answer (score 0):

Before: You are on particular node, viewing article for example.
After: It's just a block that prints title of some content type.

Try to go Content - > Vacation Tour

Comment: the problem is that "i am using this site as administrator & during setup i unchecked two options & because of that view/edit/delete/revisions tabs are disapper(you can see them in first pic "Before i change settings")& now i want them back but those two unchecked options are also disapper to recheck it.